# Facebook Graph Api 2.4 not returning names from who liked posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using facebook's Graph Api 2.4 to get who liked a users post, but the data returned does not include the name of who liked the post.

Example:

```
"likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "123456"
          }
        ],
...
```

Using Graph Api 2.3 it works:

```
"likes": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "123456",
            "name": "Name of the Person"
          }
        ],
```

...

I haven't found on the documentation anything related to this change. Is this a normal behavior of Graph Api?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is related to the update "Declarative Fields", read the changelog for v2.4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

For example: `/post-id/likes?fields=id,name`

Comment: thanks, but it is not exactly the case - Previously in 2.3, calling me/posts I can retrieve all user posts plus likes data ( id and username)... Now with 2.4, it retrieves only the id ( even specifying the fields correcly) . Using /post-id/likes?fields=id,name I would need to do a call for every post to get the user name.

Comment: that was just an example for a basic call, since you did not tell us your api call. but if it does work with 2.3 and not with 2.4 then that is EXACTLY the case ;)